# Merge columns in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am new to hive. Please help with my below problem.

I have below table in hive with one column having data with | as delimeter.

```
C1
1|2|3|4|5|6
7||9|10|11|12
```

The below one is expected output based on delimeter i want to split it as columns.

```
C1    C2   C3  C4  C5  C6
1     2    3   4   5   6
7          9   10  11  12
```

I have tried with locate and substr functions and endup with complex sql query. can you people help me in a simple way to do this.

Thank you!

Comment: is the number of columns fixed?

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala Yes, Number of columns are fixed and concated string(1|2|3|4|5|6) also will have data for six columns to split. Hope you got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `split` which returns an `array` of values from which individual elements can be selected as columns.

```
select split(c1,'\\|')[0] as c1
      ,split(c1,'\\|')[1] as c2
      ,split(c1,'\\|')[2] as c3
      ,split(c1,'\\|')[3] as c4
      ,split(c1,'\\|')[4] as c5
      ,split(c1,'\\|')[5] as c6
from tbl
```